# How to handle elasticsearch-curator log file size?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am working on the elasticsearch-curator 5.5 with following logging style in curator_config YAML:

```
logging:
  loglevel: INFO
  logfile: curator.log
  logformat: default
  blacklist: [elasticsearch]
```

Is there any way to provide maxFileSize (alike log4j configuration) here and handle the logs gracefully?
I am going to use this Curator config in a scheduled snapshot/restore job and want to retain logs.

Reference for curator config: [Elasticsearch-curator logging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.5/configfile.html#loglevel)

Comment: No, dont think so. We clean up externally.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality does not exist in Curator. Not yet, anyway.

You'd be best served to use `logrotate` (or similar) handle this for you.

Comment: Thank you @untergeek. Is there any plan to have that provision later in future?